# React PropTypes: At least one of these props must be provided

Tags: reactjs, validation, react-proptypes

Suppose my Component has 2 props.

Neither one is required, *per se*, and you could provide both, if you wished.
But you are required to provide at LEAST one of the two props.

Does PropTypes support this validation rule?

What if it's a strict XOR?

---

Note: I'm not talking about allowing one of two *types* for a known props ... which is what I understand `PropTypes.oneOf(['News', 'Photos'])` and `PropTypes.oneOfType([...types...])` to be talking about.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PropTypes allow a custom validation to be provided where you can write your own logic and own error like

```
MyComponent.propTypes = {
  News: (props, propName, componentName) => {
    if (!props.News && !props.Photos) {
      return new Error(`One among News or Photos prop must be provided`);
    }
  },

  Photos: (props, propName, componentName) => {
    if (!props.News && !props.Photos) {
      return new Error(`One among News or Photos prop must be provided`);
    }
  },
}
```

You can add further logic to specify what kind of props each one of them are

Comment: Just to add, also see Custom Validators here: https://blog.logrocket.com/validating-react-component-props-with-prop-types-ef14b29963fc